# TypeError: firebase_compat_app__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.default.storage is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

When I looked at my localhost3000, I'm having this error I couldn't understand the versions on the package it tells me the firestorage is on version 9, can anybody help me please?

[image]

and my congfig.js looks like this:

```
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import "firebase/storage";
import "firebase/firestore";
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAnalytics } from "firebase/analytics";
// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyBIwY7ZLHlm8C1xe01-kjhobEw4hDyl2H8",
  authDomain: "cega-2b708.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "cega-2b708",
  storageBucket: "cega-2b708.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "49024232943",
  appId: "1:49024232943:web:be93613bf5c036832fda1a",
  measurementId: "G-Y2LDD5JPMV",
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
const cegaStorage = firebase.storage();
const cegaFirestorage = firebase.firestore();

export { cegaStorage, cegaFirestorage };
```